# How to send mail in php

Tags: php, email

When i write a simple code to send mail it gives me warning like :

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set().

This is my code:

```
<?php

    if(mail("punam@adsoftech.com","hi","hello","from:punam@adsoftech.com"))
    echo "sent";
    else
    echo "not sent";

?>
```

Comment: Try installing http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/ it's an easy way to test mail setup

Comment: You probably don't have a SMTP server setup, Googling the warning would tell you this, along with how to go about using one

Answer (score 1):

To send an email you need a SMTP server configured to handle it.

If you want to use `mail()` function you should configure SMTP which PHP should connect to via php.ini or `ini_set()` function.

Another way is to use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), but still you will need to configure it.

Comment: Take a look into https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer There is a simple example of usage. If you want to configure `mail()` PHP function, there is a `[mail function]` section in php.ini file